# Equivalent matlab struct array in R?

Tags: r, matlab, list, struct, nested

Hello I really need your help with this one. I am processing data (running in nested for loops) during the iteration I want to end up with the following structure: Day, hour, location and values.

See attached image:

[image: Data]

For this particular example I would be looking to have a nested list of 2 elements , first element would be 300 (Day) second element would be 301(Day).

Inside first element (Day-300), we would have another list of 3 elements (Hour:1,2,3), for Hour 1 another nested list with 3 locations (loc1, loc2, loc3) and for loc1: 3 elements with the values 34,56,87, this process would be repeated over the whole set of data.